# How do I remove punctuation from a array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I need to write a method that, given a sentence, returns an array containing every other word. Punctuation needs to be removed from the word. I can get it to return every other word but I'm stuck at removing punctuation. This is what I wrote so far:

```
def alternate_words(str)
  return_array = []
  str.split.map.each_slice(2) do |x, y|
    return_array << x
  end
end
```

Comment: Provide an example of input and the expected output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see a sample of your input data, a sample call to your method, and an example of the desired output. Without that people are shooting in the dark. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 9):

Use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) to remove the characters you don't want

```
str.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.scan(/[a-z']+/i).each_slice(2).map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
str.split(/\W/)
```

In your example your function could be

```
def alternate_words(str)
  str.split(/\W/).each_slice(2).collect(&:first)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, '').split.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
```

Answer (score -1):

str.scan(/\W+/) # returns a string with only alphabets